# Spring-native on GraalVM returned non-zero result"native-image returned non-zero result error on ubuntu

Tags: spring-boot, java-17, graalvm-native-image

I am trying to build my app on ubuntu server and I faced following error:

```
/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/ty-api_feature_test-native-image/target/graalvm-reachability-metadata/c58dd12e10d1ab0d408fd3e9ef5053c2a133aa5/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-core/10.0.20 returned non-zero result ->
```

Comment: can you provide a small reproducer ?